# Spark Direct Stream - how to fetch topic data from the beginning

Tags: scala, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

We are using Spark Direct Streaming to read data from Kafka topic.

We also configured the Checkpoint location. For example if i delete the checkpoint location and redeploy/restart the application, will it pull the data from the beginning?

I hope, In Consumer based approach, when i change the group-id it will pull the data from the beginning.

**Update:** It seems we can use `auto.offset.reset' configuration in Kafka params to`smallest`, then it will start consume from the smallest.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: Could you please reply to this question?

Comment: You've answered your own question :)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: when we re-deploy the jar, do we have to delete the existing checkpoint folder and create it again? if i delete check point directory, how spark streaming manages offsets?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: You can write it as answer with all my questions :)

Comment: Yes, you have to delete them. If you want to manually resume at a given point you have to save the offsets yourself.